# Setting up VIM/ NVIM i am facing difficulty

Tags: vim, editor

hello i recently saw peoples writing their code in neo vim and vim. And this fascinates me about this. and i know that we can code in other editor tools. I want that someone teach me how to set up and i saw many installation videos which ended up with deleting all files.
I want to set up vim with plugins and some random customization. I hope that one Vimmer must help me. I tried Youtube video to set up $MYVIMRC but it does not respond to me. All end up with waste. But i am interested in VIM. Please guide me to install and configure for cpp.

Comment: [Steps to learn Vim](https://blog.joren.ga/vim-learning-steps)

Comment: how to set it up with Competitive Programming in cpp

Comment: You can try detailed written materials like step-by-step tutorials to install and configure Vim.  What matters is to use it and fix every problem you may run into. We become writers through writing. We become programmers through programming. We become Vimmers through using Vim, too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set up Vim. You *learn* it and *use* it and and your working setup  is one possible byproducts of that lifelong process.

Case in point, picking up Vim "for competitive programming" or "for programming in Python" or "for $WHATEVER" is a losing strategy because you will inevitably cut corners in order to be able to do $WHATEVER as soon as possible. Installing dozens of plugins right away, using someone else's config, because you need to be productive right here and right now are guaranteed to impede proper learning.

If you are *really* curious about Vim…

1. If you didn't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. This not a novel, go at your own pace, skip chapters, come back to them later, and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.